# redirect url in C/C++

Tags: redirect, webserver, microcontroller, mbed

I want to ask that is there any way in c/c++ to redirect to specific ip, I know there is a method in php to perform this task, but i want to know that is there any method in C/C++, as I made a webserver on mbed microcontroller using C/C++

Comment: Send a `3xx` reply code and put the redirect URL in the `Location:` header.

Comment: Location:header works only in php isn't it ??

Comment: No, it's part of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3

Answer (score 0):

The best idea to do HTTP handling is to use a higher level library that takes care of every detail. This is how it is done in other languages, like Java, Python etc.

For instance, [curlcpp](https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp) is a C++ wrapper around The powerful [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) tool, that can handle almost everything that's in the Internet.

There's a tutorial for the use of curlcpp in [Using the curl library from C++ on Windows](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2018/03/13/using-curl-library-from-c-on-windows/).